# Correct formatting in Oracle SQL for YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

The data I need to insert into my Oracle SQL database is in the format of:

```
2014/06/26 00:00:00
2014/06/26 00:00:00
2014/06/26 00:00:00
2014/06/26 00:00:00
```

When building my table, how should I create the column to insure it can handle this. (I will be inserting via a CSV file).

Comment: give the datatype as DateTime....

Comment: There's actually no choice at all.

Comment: How are you inserting from the file - via SQL*Loader, an external table, or rolling your own solution? Either way the column data type should be `DATE` if it's holding a date and time (or `TIMESTAMP` if you need fractional-second precision, which doesn't seem to be the case here). Do not be tempted to store it as a string; convert from the string to a proper `DATE` as part of the insert mechanism.

Comment: A `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` column does ***NOT*** have "a format" so it can handle *any* format you like. You need to make sure that your import program converts the values from the CSV file into a proper date value.

Comment: yes, that information should end-up as `DATE` even if you have to initially load as string

Comment: Thank you a_horse_with_no_name. If you wish, submit your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

a date data type will accept that information if your inserts are in the form

to_date('2014/06/26 00:00:00','YYYY/MM/DD hh24:mi:ss')

Comment: OP is inserting the data via a CSV file!

Comment: and it's not possible to parse that file? or load to a staging table then convert to date? leaving date information a string isn't a good solution